# int, char, and string cin and validate method?

Tags: c++, string, char, int, cin

I just finished (quite successfully) Intro to Computer Science I and II at a leading NCAA Division 1 University taught exclusively in C++, and I cannot tell you how many times I searched this site for how to accept and validate an int and only an int, a char and only a char, and a string and only a string?  Undoubtedly, there are many approaches to these questions, but typically what's on SO is very specific to a particular situation.  I'm just looking for a general method that works as requested above. I offer my method, that I worked out myself.  I can't imagine there are not others similarly situated that do or did have the same questions.  If there are other methods to do these seemingly minor tasks that a.) work, and b) involve less coding than I have outlined, I'd be interested in seeing it.

Comment: This seems too broad. There are a million ways to do something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <string>
#include<iostream>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;

int main() {

  int answer1 = 0;
  cout << "An int Question?\n"
       << "1. Yes.\n"
       << "2. No.\n";
  while (!(cin >> answer1) || answer1 < 1 || answer1 > 2) {
     cin.clear();
     cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::stream_size>::max(), '\n');
     cout << "Input Error!\n"
          << "An int Question?\n"
          << "1. Yes.\n"
          << "2. No!\n";
   }
   cout << "The int answer is " << answer1 << "\n\n";


 char answer2 = 'X';
 cout << "A char Question?\n"
      << "A. Yes.\n"
      << "B. No.\n";
 while (!(cin >> answer2) || !isalpha(answer2) || answer2 != 'A' && answer2 != 'B') {
     cin.clear();
     cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::stream_size>::max(), '\n');
     cout << "Input Error!\n"
          << "A char Question?\n"
          << "A. Yes.\n"
          << "B. No!\n";
  }
  cout << "The char answer is " << answer2 << "\n\n";


  std::string answer3 = "";
  cout << "A string Question?\n"
       << "Yes.\n"
       << "No.\n";
  while (!(cin >> answer3) || answer3 != "Yes" && answer3 != "No") {
     cin.clear();
     cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::stream_size>::max(), '\n');
     cout << "Input Error!\n"
          << "A string Question?\n"
          << "Yes.\n"
          << "No.\n";
   }
   cout << "The string answer is " << answer3 << "\n\n";
}
```

Comment: Why use 256 for the calls to `ignore`?  You should use `std::numeric_limits<std::stream_size>::max()`

Comment: @Nathan: Thanks, you are correct, and I would other than this is generally focused towards those newer to c++ and that adds a bit of complexity.

Comment: Answers should be for everyone.  Whats adding one extra thing that might have to be looked up if it makes the code less brittle?

Comment: @Nathan: OK, I'll edit it! ;)

Comment: `isalpha(answer2)` is incorrect and a good solution would be to remove it, since you go on to check for exactly the cases `'A'` and `'B'` anyway

Comment: This answer involves considerable code duplication (you repeat `cout` blocks twice) , it would be better to restructure the code to not do that